# Unable to know magento version installed

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have installed Magento 2.3 using composer, now in admin, I cannot see Magento version it show as below :

> Magento ver. No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)

EVeI i tried running below command from putty same issue there also

```
php bin/magento --version
```

> Magento CLI No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)

Comment: Can i just ask what version of composer you are using

Answer (score 1):

Mine had the same issue. I downloaded the 2.3-develop from https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.3-develop and looking at the composer.json file there is now version set in the source code. I opened my composer.json in the main install directory and added the line **"version": "2.3-dev",** between **"type"** and **"license"** lines as that is basically what my 2.2-dev code had.

Comment: This is still a problem in 2.4-develop.  Is there a reason for this or are they just not bothering to fix it?  I tried putting in "2.4-develop" but it gave me an error that it was an invalid version string.  I then put in "2.4-dev" and it worked.